# Java API and interfaces

Tags: java

```
interface OperateBicycle
```

What is the difference between Application Programming interface(Java API) and the above interface and the way they are coded/used?

Comment: Start by reading a book

Comment: We can't tell what the difference between a java interface and the code snippet you have given. What language is that? If you are asking if this is compatible with a java interface, no it is not because it violates java syntax.

Comment: The Java API are the public classes in the Java SDK, while a  interface is [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 3):

The [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) is pretty much just all of the included libraries in Java. An [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) is a concept in the programming language itself.

There's no comparison.

Answer (score 2):

## The `interface` keyword

An `interface` is a programming construct that allows programmers to decouple their code.

```
interface Event
{
    void execute();
}

class Button
{
    private Event onClickedHandler;

    public Button(Event onClickedHandler)
    {
        this.onClickedHandler = onClickedHandler;
    }

    public void clicked()
    {
        onClickHandler.execute();
    }
}
```

In this example, the `clicked` method has no idea on what `onClickHandler.execute()` will do.  Since it uses an implementation of `Event`, it allows us to change the behavior of the `clicked` method without actually changing the `Button` class.  This is especially useful if we need dozens of buttons, and all of the buttons need to have vastly different clicked behaviors.

## An API

An API is an entirely different can of worms. An API is the exposed part of a library that other libraries or applications use to interact with the library.  Although an API can be a single interface, it often isn't.

- The JAVA API is composed of hundreds of interfaces and classes.
- The Apache commons-lang API is mostly classes filled with static methods.
- If a library is written in a procedural language like C, its API would be composed of functions.
- A web service is also an API.  Instead of exposing interfaces and classes, an application or library uses the web service via HTTP requests and responses.

An `interface` doesn't need to be part of an API.  It could be private to the library, only to be used to make the library easier to maintain.